# Partial content accepting HTML as parameter in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have a concept of a modal window in my MVC application that renders some HTML that wraps content that will eventually show inside on the modal. The content will be HTML either directly hard coded in the view or generated by an Html helper as passed in as a parameter.

I'd like to wrap the modal content in a Razor template or partial in my application to avoid spreading it all over my application as it used in a number of pages. What's the easiest way of doing this? Can I achieve something similar in i partial view with out a model?

Comment: I think not getting an answer for over an hour suggests you need to put a bit more effort into your question. Maybe show us what you've tried already.

Comment: Yepp, maybe so ... Wasn't really sure how to even start testing this. But found this that shows what I'm trying to do and explains in nicely.   http://lostechies.com/hugobonacci/2011/07/11/templates-with-razor/

Comment: That's an interesting link - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a viewmodel for the partial view... a simple C# class with a string property for the Html... using the `[AllowHtml]` attribute on it will let you stuff HTML in the object.

In your parent view, stuff your HTML into this view model and pass it to the partial when you call it.